# How can I disable Shutdown Event Tracker in Windows Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, shutdown

When I want shutdown Windows Server 2008, that ask some question about reason why I want  shutdown Windows Server. How can I disable this stage (Event Tracker) in Windows Server 2008?

[image: Event Tracker]

Comment: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/disable-shutdown-event-tracker-through-group-policy/3826

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to run and open `GPedit.msc`

1. Expand *Computer Configuration*, expand *Administrative Templates*, and then expand *System*
   [image: group policy screenshot]
2. Double-click *Display Shutdown Event Tracker*.
   [image: group policy screenshot]
3. Click *Disabled*, and then click OK.
   [image: group policy screenshot]

Don't forget to run `gpupdate /force` from a command line to force refresh the GPO.